# Is there a way to provide arguments to "Execute JavaScript" in Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I need to execute the following evaluate function which should take an argumentlist

```
|@{argList}= | arg1 | arg2 | arg3 |

| Execute JavaScript | var header=document.evaluate('//span[contains(text(),"Manage VLAN Profiles")]/following::table[contains(@class,"x-grid")]/tbody/descendant::tr/descendant::td/descendant::*[contains(text(),"AccessVLAN")]',document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
return header.textContent;  |
```

Here I need to pass the `@{argList}` to the JavaScript function.

Comment: Notice that default context for JS is Selenium object, so instead of calling `document.evaluate` you might want to call `window.document.evaluate`. See http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript

Comment: Yes agreed, this helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables are simple types you can just embed them in the script and Robot Framework will expand them before actually invoking Execute JavaScript.

```
${argList}=    Create List    Sally    45
Execute JavaScript    alert('Hello ${argList[0]}, you are ${argList[1]} years old');
```

If the above does not work for you and you want to be able to pass arguments directly, you can by accessing the WebDriver instance. You can reference the arguments passed via the array called arguments.

```
${argList}=    Create List    Sally    45
${s2l}=    Get Library Instance    Selenium2Library
Call Method    ${s2l._current_browser()}    execute_script    alert('Hello ' + arguments[0] + ', you are ' + arguments[1] + ' years old');    @{argList}
```

If you want this functionality you should request it on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library). Note the on failure mechanism will not work when doing this.

Comment: This was helpful, Btw I have problem with execute javascript and document.evaluate() function as it fails with a complex xpath.. any way to sort this out?

Comment: You could use Selenium2Library's _element_find method with some XPath to get a WebElement reference and pass that reference as an argument to a JavaScript. This approach avoids document.evaluate() which will not work for IE.

Comment: anyone know same thing with appium library? it is not working