# How to execute JavaScript in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Below is my code. When I run this, it shows a WebDriverException. How do I execute JavaScript code in Robot Framework?

This, `return $(arguments[0]).data('${ToolTip}').options.title` code is doing well in -java Selenium web driver.

```
Mouse Over    ${CreateTask}
    Execute JavaScript    return $(arguments[0]).data('${ToolTip}').options.title
```

Answer (score 5):

From *http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript*:

> Note that, by default, the code will be executed in the context of the
>   Selenium object itself, so this will refer to the Selenium object. Use
>   window to refer to the window of your application, e.g.
>   window.document.getElementById('foo').

So

```
Mouse Over    ${CreateTask}
    Execute JavaScript    return window.$(arguments[0]).data('${ToolTip}').options.title
```

Assuming there is some library (jQuery most probably) that actually understands the `$` shorthand.

Comment: I am getting same issue.

Comment: Can you share us the page in question or at least a simplified version? Are you sure that your syntax is correct? It looks weird. Are you able to execute any Javascript at all? You are not storing the output of Execute Javascript to any variable, is that intentional? Does ${ToolTip} have proper value? Where does it come from?

Comment: yeah i am able to execute Execute JavaScript    document.getElementsByName("create_button")[0].click() and ${ToolTip}        xpath=//tr[2]/td[2]/span. 
Webdriver code is working correclty JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  String toolString = (String) executor.executeScript(
    "return $(arguments[0]).data('//tr[2]/td[2]/span').options.title;",
    "//tr[2]/td[2]/span");

Comment: ${title}=    Execute Javascript    return $('//tr[2]/td[2]/span').data('//tr[2]/td[2]/span').options.title;

Answer (score 2):

`arguments[0]` normally refers to arguments passed to your script.

Selenium2Library's Execute JavaScript calls 
webdriver.[execute_javascript](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) and does not pass any arguments to it. `arguments[0]` is therefore undefined.

See *[Is there a way to provide arguments to "Execute JavaScript" in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256845/is-there-a-way-to-provide-arguments-to-execute-javascript-in-robot-framework/21273554#21273554)* for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> Use any one method from below options

```js
   Execute Javascript    document.getElementById('authUser').value='admin'
 
   ${ele}    Get WebElement    id=clearPass
   Execute Javascript    arguments[0].value='pass';     ARGUMENTS    ${ele}
    
   Execute Javascript    alert(arguments[0]);    ARGUMENTS    123 
   
   Execute Javascript    document.evaluate("//*[text()='Patients']",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
    
   
   Execute Javascript    document.querySelector('[data-bind="click: changePassword"]').click();
   
   
   ${ele}    Get WebElement    //*[text()='Logout']
   Execute Javascript    arguments[0].click();     ARGUMENTS    ${ele}
```