# How can I reach a modal with RobotFramework Browser library?

Tags: modal-dialog, robotframework, playwright

There is some info regarding a Iframe,
https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/browser/how-to-work-with-iframes

But there is no information regarding how to reach a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What also works is

use a

```
 Execute Javascript  .click
```

[How to execute JavaScript in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822386/how-to-execute-javascript-in-robot-framework)

it sort of focuses the modal and then after that the keywords can be used again.

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
${handles}=   Get Window Handles
Log To Console  ${handles}
```

that strangely has some positive effect.